# Al leer un documento excel con java utilizando poi aparece el siguiente error

Tags: java

estoy leyendo un documento de excel con java utilizando poi de apache, el problema es que cuando leo un documento con pocas filas y celdas extraigo los datos sin problemas, pero si leo un documento con más filas y celdas manda un error. El error que me manda es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Beans.B_GeneraExcel.leerArchivoExcelPrueba(B_GeneraExcel.java:361)
at Beans.B_GeneraExcel.main(B_GeneraExcel.java:48)
```

C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

Este es el codigo

```
public static void leerArchivoExcelPrueba() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Archivo sujeto retenedor");
    try
    {
        //leer el archivo, se mete la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo, en este caso es xlsx por que es nueva versión
        FileInputStream archivo = new FileInputStream(new File("Anexos_Sujeto_Retenedor.xlsx")); 
        //extraer la información del archivo
        //se agrega la ioexception
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(archivo);
        //indicar con que hoja se va a  trabajar, tomandolo como un arreglo, la primera hoja va estar en la posición 0
        XSSFSheet hoja = wb.getSheetAt(0); //ingresar el número de hoja que se desea leer
        //Para tener un control de las filas y columnas, vamos a sacar cuantas filas tiene esta hoja
        int numFilas = hoja.getLastRowNum();
        //se hara mediante un for
        System.out.println("Numero de numFilas "+numFilas);
        for(int a=7;a<=numFilas;a++)
        {
            Row fila = hoja.getRow(a); //traer a la fila en la posición a
            int numCols = fila.getLastCellNum(); //con esto obtenemos cuantas columnas tiene
            //Con este for se hace el recorrido para extrar las columnas con estas variable numCols
            for (int b = 0; b < numCols; b++)
            {
                Cell celda = fila.getCell(b);
                //se realiza un switch para extraer los datos del archivo
                switch(celda.getCellType().toString())
                {
                    case "NUMERIC":
                        System.out.print(celda.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
                        break;
                    case "STRING":
                        System.out.print(celda.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                        break;
                    case "FORMULA":
                        System.out.print(celda.getCellFormula()+" ");
                        break;
                }
                
            }
            System.out.println("");//solo para hacer un salto de linea
        }
        archivo.close();
        
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(B_GeneraExcel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade una traza más completa del error, no sólo el tipo de excepción.

Comment: Listo amigo, ya realice la edición espero este bien, muchas gracias por la observación

Comment: ¿Qué ay en la línea 361?  Te dice que el objeto ahí es nulo. Verifica ese objeto.

Comment: Se encuentra esto broo, 
int numCols = fila.getLastCellNum(); //con esto obtenemos cuantas columnas tiene
Que cuentas el número de filas, el detalle es que si meto algun otro documento de excel, lo lee sin problemas

Comment: Estás seguro de que esto es correcto: `for(int a=7;a<=numFilas;a++)`? Es posible que este archivo de excel no tenga más de 7 lineas, y estás ignorando las 7 primeras con lo cual cuando entras al bucle, `hoja.getRow(a);` te devuelve `null`? Porque tu problema es que `fila` es null, por lo visto

Comment: Con eso estoy indicando que comience a leer desde la fila numero 7 ya que antes de esas filas hay texto que no quiero que lea, si me lee todo el documento y extraigo todos los datos pero cuando llega al final me manda ese error broo

Comment: Debes asegurarte de revisar cómo te va entregando las filas. Recuerda que un sheet tiene muchísimas filas, la mayoría vacías. Necesitas validar el contenido de la fila cuando comiences a recibir filas vacías para dejar de procesarlas.

Comment: Voy a checar nuevamente, creo saber por donde comenzar, el archivo de excel donde manda error es por que tiene celdas combinadas y el otro archivo no lo tiene, entonces voy a comenzar por ahí, si soluciono el problema les comento, vale

Answer (score 0):

tu ejemplo no es muy claro pero te puedo mostrar cómo cargo un archivo excel a una table de mi base de datos. Esta es la lógica que uso en mi clase Service y no he presentado problema alguno.

```
@Autowired
    ILog_sap_existenciaRepository lR;

 @Override
    public int saveDataFromUploadfile(MultipartFile file) {
        int inFlag = 0;
        lR.borrarregistros();
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
        if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("xls") || extension.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
            inFlag = readDataFromExcel(file);
            
            return inFlag;
            
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }




private Workbook getWorkBook(MultipartFile file) {

        Workbook workbook = null;
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {

                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());

            } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {

                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return workbook;
    }





private int readDataFromExcel(MultipartFile file) {

        Workbook workbook = getWorkBook(file);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();
        rows.next();
        Integer c = 1;
        try {

            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rows.next();
                Log_sap_existencia log_sap_existencia = new Log_sap_existencia();
                //////////////////////// //////

                if ((row.getCell(0) != null) || (row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().length() < 0)) {
                    if (row.getCell(0).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String material = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setMaterial(material);

                    } else if (row.getCell(0).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setMaterial(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }

                if (row.getCell(1) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(1).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String texto = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setTexto(texto);

                    } else if (row.getCell(1).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setTexto(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setTexto(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setTexto(null);
                }
                
                
                if (row.getCell(2) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(2).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String centro = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setCentro(centro);

                    } else if (row.getCell(2).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setCentro(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setCentro(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setCentro(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(3) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(3).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String almacen = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setAlmacen(almacen);

                    } else if (row.getCell(3).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setAlmacen(row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setAlmacen(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setAlmacen(null);
                }
                
                
                if (row.getCell(4) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(4).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String umb = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setUmb(umb);
                    } else if (row.getCell(4).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setUmb(row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setUmb(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setUmb(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(5) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(5).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String denom = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setDenom(denom);
                    } else if (row.getCell(5).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setDenom(row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setDenom(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setDenom(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(6) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(6).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String libre_util = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(6).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setLibre_util(libre_util);
                    } else if (row.getCell(6).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setLibre_util(row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setLibre_util(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setLibre_util(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(7) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(7).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String valor_libre_util = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(7).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setValor_libre_util(valor_libre_util);
                    } else if (row.getCell(7).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setValor_libre_util(row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setValor_libre_util(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setValor_libre_util(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(8) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(8).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String valor_transito = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setValor_transito(valor_transito);
                    } else if (row.getCell(8).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setValor_transito(row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setValor_transito(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setValor_transito(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(9) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(9).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String stock_transito = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(9).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setStock_transito(stock_transito);
                    } else if (row.getCell(9).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setStock_transito(row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setStock_transito(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setStock_transito(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(10) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(10).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String lote = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(10).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setLote(lote);
                    } else if (row.getCell(10).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setLote(row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setLote(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setLote(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(11) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(11).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String acreedor = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(11).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setAcreedor(acreedor);
                    } else if (row.getCell(11).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setAcreedor(row.getCell(11).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setAcreedor(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setAcreedor(null);
                }
                
                if (row.getCell(12) != null) {
                    if (row.getCell(12).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                        String tipo = NumberToTextConverter.toText(row.getCell(12).getNumericCellValue());
                        log_sap_existencia.setTipo(tipo);
                    } else if (row.getCell(12).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                        log_sap_existencia.setTipo(row.getCell(12).getStringCellValue());
                    } else {
                        log_sap_existencia.setTipo(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    log_sap_existencia.setTipo(null);
                }
                
                

                lR.save(log_sap_existencia);

            
                

            } // while

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 2;
        }

        return c;

    }//fin
```

Comment: Hola que tal, muchas gracias por tu ayuda me ha servido bastante, de verdad muchas gracias